# How to delete/destroy/make nil any object with ARC?

Tags: ios, object

Every time I show some subView with this code, clearImage creates every time, and after 10 executions there are 10 images!
How to delete this image after **removeFromSuperview**?

```
- (IBAction)nextTutorial:(id)sender {
    UIImageView *clearImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 0, 50, 50)];
    clearImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[settings objectAtIndex:7]];

    UIImageView *helpImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    helpImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[settings objectAtIndex:8]];

    UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 7, 200, 30)];
    slider.value = 0.5;

    if (hintnumber == 1) {
        self.hintLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:1];
        [self.view addSubview:slider];
        hintnumber = 2;
    } else if (hintnumber == 2) {
        self.hintLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:2];
        [self.view addSubview:clearImage];
        hintnumber = 3;
    } else if (hintnumber == 3) {
        self.hintLabel.text = [settings objectAtIndex:3];
        [self.view addSubview:helpImage];
        [self.nextButton setTitle:[settings objectAtIndex:5] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        hintnumber = 4;
    } else if (hintnumber == 4) {
        hintnumber = 1;
        [slider removeFromSuperview];
        [clearImage removeFromSuperview];
        [helpImage removeFromSuperview];
        slider = nil;
        clearImage = nil;
        helpImage = nil;

        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE based on new code:

If hintNumber is 4, you are creating an object, never adding it to a view, and then removing it from a view that it isn't in.  You need to remove the object that was added previously from it's superview, and not the one that you just created using something like `[[self.view viewWithTag:99] removeFromSuperview];` and set the tag number of clearView to 99 when you create it.

As an aside, you should only create the new objects when you need them.

Comment: The irony in the fact, that I cant even do them hidden o_O

Comment: Okay, so either the second part of code is not being called, or clearImage is not valid at the point that you are calling it.  You will need to post some more code for us to determine what the problem is, but you **definitely** need to call `removeFromSuperview` before setting clearImage to `nil`.

Comment: DEBUG:  clearImage is: <UIImageView: 0x68aef40; frame = (270 0; 50 50); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x68651f0>>

Comment: If I write structure like this:

`If (number = 1) { create object 1, add subview}
If (number = 2) { create object 2 add subview }
If (number = 3) { create object 3 add subview }
If (number = 4) {but how to invoke removeFromSuperview  from here?}`

Thats why I create object off the `if()`

Comment: Something like: `{ create object1, object1.tag = 99; add subview }`  and then if `(number = 4) { [[self.view viewWithTag:99] removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Make sure that you use a different tag number for each different view that you are adding!  (i.e. for clearImage, helpImage, and slider).

Comment: It is good, that it works, but it would be better if I knew WHY it is so. Can you explain please?

Comment: Sure!  The tag property on a view is used in order to be able to "find" it again later.  So when you set the tag of clearImage to 99, you are able to ask the view that contains it for "the view with tag 99" and it returns it (in the function viewWithTag) so that you can then make changes to it/remove it from its' superview.

Answer (score 1):

First: remove from superview

Second: set clearImage to nil ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call [clearImage removeFromSuperview] before setting clearImage to nil. :)